# IIS 7.5 Application Pool stops on page request

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, application-pools

I have problem with IIS and application pools. I have add a blank (with one test HTML file) web site with application pool. When I do a request to this web site in causes application pool of this site to stop. Why does the application pool stopping for each request?
This is happening with my ASP.NET application, so I decided to make a simple as possible test (this new basic web site with HTML file) and here is happening the same. Did I missed some setting? I am using a Windows Server 2008 R2. I have registered ASP.NET 2.0 framework to IIS.

I have installed some extensions:

- application warm up
- deployment extensions

Comment: Is there anything in the event log?

Comment: If the app pool is just shutting down (not crashing) this sounds like it could be something with the app pool recycling settings. In advanced options there are settings for "Generate Recycle Event Log Entry" - try turning all of those to True and see if a recycle is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well problem was really funny. I was missing **"HTTP Redirection"** feature. I have installed it and now app pools working properly.